# Why is my SSD slowing down halfway through the gnome-disk benchmark?

Tags: linux, ssd, gnome

Can someone please explain a few bits about the results of this benchmark.

This was tested on an SSD:
[image: Inlined image with benchmark results]

First thing I'd like to know is why it slowed WAY down in the end.. I'm wondering if it's heating maybe? or am I crazy...

The second thing I'd really like to know is what the little spikes mean, they're fairly consistent and I'm wondering why they exist.

Comment: Because TLC is so slow, these SSDs have “emulated SLC” caches. They’re only relevant when writing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

It is *probably* an interaction between "physical" disk construction and controller, "logical" chunk size, and software write requests (if I got that right) such that (for instance) transferring a file in larger chunks (1MB) can be a lot faster than the same amount written in smaller (4KB) chunks.

The exact sizes vary based on manufacturing and file system. I think NTFS defaults to 4KB for example. And some of the OS choices for filesystems are a compromise between large file and small file performance.

HDDs have a flatter curve, but can actually outperform SSD in certain circumstances. So look into that. related reading:

https://serverfault.com/questions/7531/would-ssd-drives-benefit-from-a-non-default-allocation-unit-size

All that being said, I would defer to someone with more hardware experience.

Comment: I *think* on-disk controllers are free to queue writes for a more advantageous moment and some may allow software to "flag as important" to flush the queue. This will have an effect on benchmarks, and I think benchmarks can sometimes fail to signal such things. Again, implementation specific.